# Reg ex required for finding two ||

Tags: regex

My text file has lots of lines like this :

```
12345|any string |5585|more string|yet more string|safdowdjfpd|wdfiojeif
```

I want to find the one line that has this, an empty value before code :

```
12345|any string|5585||yet more string|safdowdjfpd|wdfiojeif
```

There are also other lines in file that have empty strings, so it must be only the 3rd and 4th pipe symbols that are caught.

Comment: [tag:regex] - "Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches any string that contains consecutive pipes, these being the 3rd and 4th pipes of the string:

`^[^|]+\|[^|]+\|[^|]+\|\|`

Matches:

`12345|any string|5585||yet more string|safdowdjfpd|wdfiojeif`

Doesn't match:

```
12|345|any string|5585||yet more string|safdowdjfpd|wdfiojeif
12345|any string|5585|yet more string|safdowdjfpd|wdfiojeif
```

Answer (score 1):

A pretty simple string match:

```
/\|\|..\|/
```

This matches || followed by any two characters and ending with |

Comment: ok thanks the code not always CODE it is any combo of two chars, updated question

Comment: That is not obvious from your question but I have updated by answer to match your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
/.*\|.*\|.*\|\|.*/
```

Tested with egrep

```
[root@srv test]# echo "12345|any string|5585|annoying string|CODE|safdowdjfpd|wdfiojeif" | egrep -o ".*\|.*\|.*\|\|.*"
[root@srv test]#

[root@srv test]# echo "12345|any string|5585||CODE|safdowdjfpd|wdfiojeif" | egrep -o ".*\|.*\|.*\|\|.*"
12345|any string|5585||CODE|safdowdjfpd|wdfiojeif
[root@srv test]#
```

Answer (score 0):

What patterns have you tried so far? Was `\\|{2}` among them?

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of [any characters] in that position:

```
/.+\|.+\|.+{0}\|.+\|.+\|.+\|.+/
```